# How to save page views to a text file in php?

Tags: php, file

I am trying to save page views in a txt file. So when the page is visited the script will update the txt file and the number will increase by +1.

My `page_views.txt` file contains the following contents :

```
 [page_views]
```

`[page_views]` is the number of page views eg : [500] and it should update every time the page is visited.

**save_hits.php**

```
<?Php
$f=file("p.txt");
$getc=$f[0];
$addition=$getc. '+1';
$f_ope=fopen("p.txt","w");
fputs($f_ope,$addition);
fclose($f_ope);
?>
```

**page_hits.php**

```
<?Php 
$x=file("p.txt");
echo "+$x[0] views";?>
```

But the problem is that it is not working as expected,

Whenever the `page_hits.php` script is run I get the result:

```
1+1+1+1 views
```

Where the expected output should be  :

```
4 views
```

and it should increase by +1 on every hit.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$addition=$getc. '+1';` Means [appending](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

`.` stands for concat operator.

So, The value for `$addition` at the end of execution will be look like `1+1+1+1`

But if you need to add then should do  `$addition = $getc + 1;` which will result in total summation.

So, You should replace `$addition = $getc. '+1'` with `$addition = $getc + 1;` to get the total summation.

Answer (score 3):

use the below code:

```
$fh = fopen('p.txt','r');
$cont = '';
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  $cont = $cont.$line;
}
fclose($fh);
$addition = $cont+1;
$f_ope=fopen("p.txt","w");
fputs($f_ope,$addition);
fclose($f_ope);
```

Answer (score 2):

By the result you can clearly see you are appending '+1' instead of adding 1 to the sum

change `$addition = $getc. '+1';`
to `$addition = $getc + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

```
$count = intval(file_get_contents("p.txt"));
file_put_contents("p.txt",++$count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey there is small mistake you are doing. The problem is you want to `add` but you are concating the variable from the `.txt file`. This is a quick fix to your problem ,just correct the line which contains the concat of the string with `+1`. 
`$addition=$getc. '+1';` to the following.

```
$addition=$getc + 1;
```

This will solve the problem.

Other way is to use `++$getc` and after doing this write to the `file` again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
    $fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r+");

while(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    // waiting to lock the file
}

$count = intval(file_get_contents("counter.txt"));
file_put_contents(".txt",++$count);

ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
fwrite($fp, $counter);  // set your data
fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock

fclose($fp);
```